# Finding the current render MIME type from a Rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

I'm looking for a way to find which render type I am currently executing from a helper. Mostly to do something like this:

```
# some_helper.rb
def url_to_faq
  if plain_text_render
    ...
  else
   # HTML
  end
end
```

We've used a workaround override for `render` in a gem that we are using, but it's gross. Is there some official way to get at the renderer metadata, either in Rails 4 or Rails 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use presenter here.

In controller:

```
@link_presenter = LinkPresenter.new(format: request.format.symbol, view: view_context)
```

Link presenter class:

```
class LinkPresenter
  def initialize(format:, view:)
     @format = format
     @view = view
  end

  def url_to_faq
    if format == :html
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

then in the view:

```
@link_presenter.url_to_faq
```

By passing view_context to presenter you get access to view helpers. If not needed, then drop it.

Nice article about Presenters: [Presenters in Rails by Nithin Bekal](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-presenters/)

Comment: Nope, that's definitely not what I'm after, sorry. I know the "clean" way to do this is explicit dependency injection, but I'm looking for introspection instead.

Comment: Wait... `request.format.symbol`! That's what I was looking for, thanks!